# Incorrect presentation timestamps when seeking backwards through MP4 video

Tags: android, video, h.264, android-video-player, mpeg-4

I'm using `MediaCodec` and `MediaExtractor` to play video at variable rates, both forwards and backwards.  The code is using something like [SpeedControlCallback](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/SpeedControlCallback.java) to establish inter-frame pauses - feeding it the `presentationTimeUs` field from the output buffers.

This works fine, 99% of the time, however it seems like the AVC codec on the **Samsung S6** provides incorrect presentation times when seeking  backwards - they're pinned at whatever the highest value was when seeking forwards, if that makes any sense.  The data in the buffers is correct / changing - it just doesn't correspond to the fixed presentation time.

The S6 can handle backward seeks in MP4 files with a brand/ftype of `avc1`, but other-branded H.264 video I've tried (`mp42`, `isom`) don't work 100% of the time.  The same files work fine on a Samsung S5, and every other device I've tried.

The codec logs this:

`09-15 11:16:21.611   2992-16618/? W/EXYNOS_VIDEO_DEC﹕ sCurrentTimestamp(6002033) is smaller than latestTimeStamp(7001744), uses latestTimeStamp`

At each backwards seek (`SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC`), and will provide that erroneous `latestTimestampValue` for all of the keyframes.

Has anybody encountered a similar problem with the AVC codec on the Galaxy S6, or is in a position to offer any (non-hacky) solutions?

Comment: What is the question? You probably found a bug around playing certain AVC files on certain hardware backwards. Video is hard, seeking is harder and playing backwards is even harder. Depending on the GOP structure - you have to decode forward, hold the decoded frames in memory and then pass them backwards. Again - what do you like to know?

Comment: Apologies for omitting a defined question - I am curious about whether anybody else has encountered this specific bug on this specific hardware.